# Время сервера

Tags: настройка, php, сервер, vps, mysql

Снимаю VPS. В ispmanager изменил часовой пояс на Europe/Kiev (+3), а дата и в php и в mysql не та.

Должно быть: Tue, 27 May 2014 19:35:09 +0300
А выводит: Tue, 27 May 2014 15:20:09 +0300

Помогити нестроить сервер, я в этом чайник! Очень нужно!

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у вас должен быть root доступ к серверу? Зайдите по ssh и смените часовой пояс. На всякий, перезапустите веб сервер

Comment: Да, root есть, но как єто сделать по ssh? как работать с ssh я не вкурсе... куда копать? эсть ссылки на инструкции как это сделать?

Comment: Доступ к root есть не всегда, и довольно - таки часто, часовые пояса между php и БД различаются. Как вариант, предлагаю пользоваться не timestamp'ом, а datetime и дату передавать из PHP при инсерте/апдейте.

Comment: root точно эсть! И в php и mysql - время одинаковое! часовой пояс и там и там +0300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать

```
date_default_timezone_set('[timezone]');
```

Например:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Yekaterinburg');
```

Comment: Часововой пояс правильный! Я и в php.ini прописал, и Вашим методом... не помогает... пояс тот, а время нет...

Comment: Покажите вывод ls -l /etc/timezone , возможно просто нет прав на чтение. Иногда такое бывает.

Comment: Спасибо! Настроил время сервера вручную!